# Count the frequency of each elements in a DataGridView in .Net Windows Application Form

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms

I have some datasets that I read from csv files into DataGridViews and I need to plot some charts where I count the frequency of each different variable on each column.
I found a [code](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-frequencies-of-array-elements/) that count the frequency of array elements and then print them, I tried using the same logic on my datagrid.
I started with a column ("SEX" column) that has only 2 values (`2.0` or `1.0`), but when I try to view the count result I always get `1` (which means it didn't count a thing). It's supposed to show the count of the last different value found in the column (in my case `2.0` which has 140ish occurence).

Edit: I tried appending the count result to the textbox and I see that I end up with `1` for each loop, while I am supposed to get only 2 values (which are the count `2.0`and then the count of `1.0`)

[image: screenshot of the results]
I also need to plot the output, so I am guessing I could use a dictionary where I store the variable name + the frequency.

```
public void countFreq() //function to count the frequency of each var in a column -not working yet-
        {
            var n = dataGridView1.RowCount;

            var visited = new bool[n];

            // Traverse through array elements and
            // count frequencies
            for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                // Skip this element if already processed
                if (visited[i] || dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["SEX"].Value
                    == null)
                    continue;
                // Count frequency
                var count = 1;
                for (var j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
                    if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["SEX"].Value == dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells["SEX"].Value)
                    {
                        visited[j] = true;
                        count++;
                    }

                textFile.Text += count.ToString(); //for testing purposes I used a textfield to print the last count value
            }
        }
```

I know that for a column where the values are explicit I can just loop on my datagrid rows and use the count method (which I did) but for most my data I don't explicitly know the values in each row so I needed to find a way to do that.

Comment: It is difficult to understand what problem you are having and what you are trying to count. I have no clue what the posted code is supposed to do. Are you trying to get the number of 1’s and 2’s in the sex column?

Comment: @JohnG yes, I used the 1 and 2 as an example but I am looking to find the frequency of each different value in a given column in my datagrid. The values are generally unknow so I can just use something like `if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["SEX"].Value.ToString() == "1.0")
                        count++;`

Comment: I would suggest using a `Dictionary` where the value found is the key, and the value is the count.

Comment: @JohnG the thing is I don't know what value are to be found in some columns so I can't explicitly use this condition there, i.e `if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["RandomColumn"].Value.ToString() == "RandomValue")` And the solution I tried here doesn't seem to work like it should

Comment: I am not following what you mean. Are you trying to find all the "different" values in a column in addition to how many times each "different" value is found in that column?

Comment: @JohnG yes something like that, I added a screenshot of what happens with my current code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for. In addition, the code below loops through the rows in the grid, however, if the grid has a data source I suggest looping though that collection instead of the grid rows.

Below is a method that takes a column index and returns a `Dictionary<string, int>`. A simple loop through each cell in the given column and if the cell's `Value` is not in the dictionary, we will add it. If the cells value is already in the dictionary will simply increment its `int` `Value`. After the loop finishes, the dictionary is returned. Something like…

```
private Dictionary<string, int> GetCountOfValues(string columnName) {
  string curKey = "";
  Dictionary<string, int> valuesAndCounts = new Dictionary<string, int>();
  foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows) {
    if (!row.IsNewRow) {
      if (row.Cells[columnName].Value != null) {
        curKey = row.Cells[columnName].Value.ToString();
        if (valuesAndCounts.ContainsKey(curKey)) {
          valuesAndCounts[curKey]++;
        }
        else {
          valuesAndCounts.Add(curKey, 1);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return valuesAndCounts;
}
```

Usage may look something like…

```
Dictionary<string, int> column0Counts = GetCountOfValues("Col0");
Dictionary<string, int> column1Counts = GetCountOfValues("Date");
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, I am so thankful for the help. Just to complete this if someone needs it someday, if you want to print the pairs you can use something like this `foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> kvp in column0Counts)
            {
                textFile.Text += string.Format("Key = {0}, Value = {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
            }`

Answer (score 1):

You should really load your CSV data into a datatable and then query that

```
var dt = SomeFunctionThatReadsCsvIntoDatatable(..);

yourDataGridView.DataSource = dt;
```

---

Your query is then answered, simply, by grouping the datatable using linq;

```
(yourDataGridView.DataSource as DataTable).Rows
    .Cast<DataRow>()
    .GroupBy(r => r["someColumn"])
    .Select(g => new { K = g.Key, C = g.Count() });
```

- `"someColumn"` would be `"SEX"`
- K would end up as an `object` holding whatever Type the data is ` - it's hard to tell from the information posted whether you've just got your csv as strings or whether they're eg doubles, dates etc

If you want to do it for all columns, it would probably be easiest to do it in a loop on the datatable Columns collection. DataColumn.ColumnName provides the "someColumn"

Comment: Yes I am using a dt for reading data, I don't really think I am supposed to use linq. Anyways @JohnG solution works just fine.